# Query in query in query

Tags: php, mysql

I have problems getting this to work. I have also tried the queries inside of eachother, but it doesnt work. Somebody know why?

```
$ligan  = mysql_query("SELECT leagueId FROM league WHERE leagueName='$leagueName'");
$laget  = mysql_query("SELECT teamid FROM team WHERE leagueId='$ligan'");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM player WHERE teamId='laget'");
```

This is where it is printed...

```
            <?php
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
            echo $result;
            }
            else{
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['playerName'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['birthday'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['height'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['madeGoals'] . "</td>";

                  echo "</tr>";


                  }
            }
                mysql_close($db); ?>
```

I get this problem:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

I believe that ligan gives one value
while laget gives alot.

Can you help?

Comment: what is the error? please describe your problem better

Comment: I don't know if that's a typo but in the last query you forgot the `$` in the `laget` variable.

Comment: yes it is a typo! Sorry!

Comment: The problem is that ligan gets one value while laget gets several. I think that is the problem

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why those answers are not suggesting you to use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), I think it is easier to work and the reason it was created is to solve problems like yours.

Yes, you have a PHP error about the `mysql_query` as all answers pointed.

My suggestion is, learn about [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

I think that your code would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM player
INNER JOIN team on team.leagueId = league.id
INNER JOIN league on league.name = '$leagueName'
```

Give [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) a try and I guarantee your code will look better and your life easier =)

Comment: The other answers are a little scary... I hope that these people just don't actually write SQL like that…

Comment: Now it says  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: Use that SQL on you database and it will give you the results or a more detailed error(if any). What are you using to manage your database?

Comment: That basically means that the query returned `false` - i.e. something is wrong withe the query – perhaps a field or table has a typo somewhere?

Comment: @user2280125 please run the SQL in your database and show us the results ;)

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query() returns a resultset, not a result itself.  You must fetch the result out of the resultset.

In this example, I check the resultset to ensure there are results before accessing the first result inside of it.

```
$resultset = mysql_query("SELECT leagueId from league WHERE leagueName='$leagueName'");

if( mysql_num_rows( $resultset ) > 0 ){
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $resultset );
  // access the ID via $row['leagueId']
}
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you! How do you mean that I should access the ID via $row['leagueId']. Im very new at this. Sorry

Comment: Inside of the `if` you can then use `$row['leagueId']` in the way you would use any other variable.  `echo( $row['leagueId'] )` will display the leagueId, or you can assign the value to its own variable with  `$leagueId = $row['leagueId']`, etc.  However, if you are going to be doing several lookups like in your question, using JOINs like Gerep suggested will give you cleaner and faster code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query(
  "SELECT * FROM player WHERE teamId IN (
    SELECT teamid from team WHERE leagueId IN (
      SELECT leagueId from league WHERE leagueName='$leagueName'
    )
  )"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont fetch reslts to variables, you just execute queries.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT leagueId from league WHERE leagueName='$leagueName'");    
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT teamid from team WHERE leagueId='$row[0]'");    
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM player WHERE teamId='$row[0]'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["name"];
    echo $row["surname"];        
}
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you very much. This did not fully work. It only returned some of the players and not all in the league chosen...

Comment: @user2280125 I updated the code in answer. You need to fetch data from the last result in loop. My code prints players name and surnames but there should be your table's fields, of course.